# Mirroring SQL 2008 R2 database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have just started as a DBA and my first task is to move a 4TB database from a physical server to a virtual server with little down time.

I have found a way to copy the database across, but not how to keep it up to date without having a current full/log backup.

Does any one know of a way I can mirror the database without having to make a full backup and mirror transaction logs?

Comment: There's very big for a database to be 4TB. Or you referring to multiple databases that add up to 4TB? Nonetheless, mirroring is probably one of the least downtime to move the database. Is this 4TB database transactions intensive?

Comment: This is one database that's 4TB in size. I've done a copy database and then tried to configure mirroring but it tells me that there are bulk changes and needs to have the last log file restored. This is the part I'm looking to get round. 
The Database is very transaction intensive.

Comment: Is there anytime or days where the load will be lesser?

Comment: No Its a 24/7 system

Comment: Why does applying log backups pose an issue? How often are you taking them?

Comment: The database is in simple recovery mode so it's not taking log backups..... I have only just started and this is the estate I'm walking into, the previous DBA walked out a week before I started.

Comment: There are also third-party tools that can be used to mirror files at the host level that could do this.  I used to work for Double-Take, which was purchased by Carbonite last year, and it could be used for a migration like this.  The downtime required to switch would be the amount of time to attach the DB on the new server, plus whatever it takes for your client connection config.

Comment: Have you tried to take a full backup before on this 4TB DB? How long does it takes? And how big is your log size?

Answer (score 1):

> I have just started as a DBA

Solving problems using Backup and Restore is the bread-and-butter of a DBA.

> move a 4TB database from a physical server to a virtual server with little down time.

Define "little".

The safest, simplest thing is to leave the database in Simple recovery, and use Full/Differential backups to move the data.

You can also switch to Full recovery and use Log backups instead of Differential backups.

In both cases you would

1) Take a Full backup

2) Restore the Full backup on the new server WITH NORECOVERY

3) Begin Downtime

4) Take a final Log Backup or Differential Backup

5) Restore the all the Log Backups or the Differential Backup WITH RECOVERY

6) Set the database OFFLINE on the old server

7) End Downtime

You can perform steps 1, 2, 4, and 5 as many times as you want in testing, and to measure the required downtime.